# Text around element in Zend_Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-decorators

So I've created a simple Zend_Form and I would like to display one of its element in this way:

```
Label:      text [input] text2
```

I've used LabelDecorator to add label successfully and I can even use DescriptionDecorator to add text1 or text2 as a descrption, but I couldn't figure out how to add both of them. I know I can add two DescriptionDecorators, one prepended and one appended, but both of them have the same content.

Comment: Show us some code? And look into Zend_Form viewhelpers you can then output the form which ever way you like.

Comment: I have no idea what code should I show... It's just something like `$element = $form->getElement('name');` and the form itself is defined in an ini file. Element is just a simple text input. Viewhelper seems to be some kind of answer, though it won't be very flexible (correct me if I'm wrong but I think I would have to override default viewhelper, that I'm using across the whole system).

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own decorator:

```
class My_Form_Decorator_PlainText extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract
{
    public function render($content)
    {
        return $content . $this->getOption('text');
    }
}
```

and then add this decorator multiple times:

```
$this->addElement($this->createElement('text', 'fieldname')
        ->setLabel('Label')
        ->addPrefixPath('My_Form', 'My/Form/')
        ->setDecorators(array(
            'Label',
            array(array('before'=>'PlainText'), array('text' => 'hello')),
            'ViewHelper',
            array(array('after'=>'PlainText'), array('text' => 'world')),
        )));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up creating a custom form decorator:

```
<?php
/** Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract */
require_once 'Zend/Form/Decorator/Abstract.php';

class Zend_Form_Decorator_Surrounded extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Render element
     *
     * @param  string $content
     * @return string
     */
    public function render($content)
    {
        $options   = $this->getOptions();
        if(!isset($options['text'])) return $content;

        return sprintf($options['text'], $content);
    }
}
?>
```

And I use it this way:

```
<?php
$element->setDecorators(array(
    'ViewHelper', 
    'Errors',
    array('Surrounded', array('text' => 'text1 %s text2')),
    'HtmlTag',
));
?>
```

Do you think it's a good solution, are there any disadvanteges of it?